# How to checkbox in table displaying one query result based on other query result?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I have two SQL queries, one that queries all packages in one DB table, then one that queries an assignments table and should output all package ID's that match the company ID in the query, e.g.:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM pkgs");
$curPkgs = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT pid FROM assignments where subdom = '".$curCompany."'");
```

It then outputs the packages to a HTML table, and what I want is that if this package ID exists in the second query for a checkbox to be checked in the table.

What I have for that is

```
$currow = mysqli_fetch_array($curPkgs);


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $disLine = $row['id'];

    if(in_array($disLine,$currow)){
            $yas = "checked";
    } else {
            $yas = "not";
    }

       echo "<tr>";

    if($yas = "checked"){
            echo "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><input name=\"checkbox\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$row['id']."\" checked></td>";
    } else {
            echo "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><input name=\"checkbox\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$row['id']."\"></td>";
    }


    echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['pname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['version'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['rdate'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

The behaviour I get is all packages are outputted to the table as expected but I think the $yas variable stays as "checked" because what I get is the box checked next to every row instead of just one row.

Comment: Also, if I add a var_dump for $disLine and a var_dump for $currow just under my while statement I get: NULL array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "4" } NULL array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "4" } NULL array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "4" } NULL array(1) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "4" }

Comment: The query (select pid form assignments...) should return one value which is '4' from the assignments table. Please forgive my ignorance!

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
if($yas = "checked")  >> you are missing a equal symbol here
```

to

```
if($yas == "checked")
```